# Sum only numerical columns and divide values by total

Tags: r

I am having trouble with some calculations on a data frame.

Here is my DF (with many more rows and columns)

What I am trying to do is:

Step (1) - For each month I would like to sum the assets columns. For example
all the assets_Jan_2018 and output as a DF.

Step (2) - Then, for each firm, I would like to divide assets each month by the total for the month, i.e. the values calculated in step (1). For example, 
Firm A Jan_2018 = 210234/1466742 = 0.14334

Step (3) - Then I would like to take the values from step (2) and multiply by the corresponding returns. =0.143334*4.5 = 0.645003

Step (4) - Finally, I would like to sum each column in step (3) and output as a DF

```
 Firm   Assets_Jan_2018  Assets_ Feb_2018 Returns_Jan_2018 Returns_Feb_2018
 A          210234             235425           4.5            6.7
 B          123144             127124           5.3            1.2
 c          897897             789798           1.4            6.2
 D          235467             897342           9.7            3.2
```

I tried colSums and many other things but kept getting error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a lot less concise then Ronak's answer, but demonstrates the sweep functionality.

Construct example df:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind(Firm = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
                       Assets_Jan_2018 = as.numeric(c(210234, 123144, 897897, 235467)),
                       Assets_Feb_2018 = as.numeric(c(235425, 127124, 789798, 897342)),
                       Returns_Jan_2018 = as.double(c(4.5,  5.3,  1.4, 9.7)),
                       Returns_Feb_2019 = as.double(c(6.7, 1.2, 6.2, 3.2))))
```

Ensure numeric data types:

```
df <- type.convert(df)
```

Calculate the weighted returns:

```
FirmWeightedReturns <- cbind(Firm = df$Firm,
                             sweep(df[sapply(df, is.numeric) & !(grepl("returns", tolower(colnames(df))))],
                                   2,
                                   as.numeric(sapply(df[sapply(df, is.numeric) & !(grepl("returns", tolower(colnames(df))))], sum)), '/')
                                  * df[grepl("returns", tolower(colnames(df)))])
```

Summarise as a df:

```
TotalReturns <- data.frame(lapply(FirmWeightedReturns[sapply(FirmWeightedReturns, is.numeric)], sum))
```

Output to console:

```
TotalReturns
```

Answer (score 3):

We can first separate `"Assets"` and `"Returns"` columns and then use `colSums` and multiply values accordingly

```
asset_col <- grep("^Assets", names(df1))
return_col <- grep("^Returns", names(df1))
colSums(t(t(df1[asset_col])/colSums(df1[asset_col])) * df1[return_col])

#Returns_Jan_2018 Returns_Feb_2018 
#        3.504230         4.633941
```

---

To break it down and make clear each step

Step 1 -  For each month I would like to sum the assets columns

```
colSums(df1[asset_col])
#Assets_Jan_2018 Assets_Feb_2018 
#    1466742         2049689
```

Step 2 - For each firm, I would like to divide assets each month by the total for the month

```
t(t(df1[asset_col])/colSums(df1[asset_col]))
#     Assets_Jan_2018 Assets_Feb_2018
#[1,]      0.14333400      0.11485889
#[2,]      0.08395751      0.06202112
#[3,]      0.61217106      0.38532577
#[4,]      0.16053744      0.43779422
```

Step 3 - Then I would like to take the values from step (2) and multiply by the corresponding returns

```
t(t(df1[asset_col])/colSums(df1[asset_col])) * df1[return_col]

#  Returns_Jan_2018 Returns_Feb_2018
#1        0.6450030       0.76955455
#2        0.4449748       0.07442534
#3        0.8570395       2.38901980
#4        1.5572131       1.40094151
```

Step 4 - I would like to sum each column in step (3)

```
colSums(t(t(df1[asset_col])/colSums(df1[asset_col])) * df1[return_col])

#Returns_Jan_2018 Returns_Feb_2018 
#        3.504230         4.633941
```

Comment: @ronakShar - Thank you so much for your help. Quick question, how do I output the final step as a dataframe?

Comment: @CISCO Use `stack(colSums(df1[asset_col]/colSums(df1[asset_col]) * df1[return_col]))` Or `data.frame(v1 = colSums(df1[asset_col]/colSums(df1[asset_col]) * df1[return_col]))`

Comment: Hi @ronakShar - Firstly, thanks for your help. I just realized that there is an error from step 2 to 4. I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

Comment: @ronakShar - For example, in step 2 column 1 row 2, the value should be 123,144/1,466,724 = 0.083958 not 0.0601. It looks like a similar error is occurring in step 3 and 4. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: @CISCO I see. Thanks for informing. I have corrected the answer. Hope it should be fine now, please check.

Comment: @CISCO To understand consider this example, `df <- as.data.frame(matrix(1:10, ncol = 2));` Now imagine we want to multiply first column by 1 and second column by 2. Check the difference in output between `df * c(1, 2)` and `t(t(df) * c(1, 2))`. That is the reason for double `t(t(` ... Hope this will make it more clear.